# How can I read a pdf file with express and node

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, nodes

I'm trying to read a pdf... and my idea is to convert it to a text. I have read the pdf-parser documentation and I don't understand why it is giving me this error, has anyone ever used pdf-parser?
Has anyone had this error?
It would be very helpful, I have never worked with it and the videos I watched use it very easily, but it breaks the code for me.

```
const url = require("./prueba.pdf");
const pdf = require("pdf-parse");
const fs = require("fs");

const pdffile = fs.readFileSync(url);
console.log(pdffile);
pdf(pdffile).then(function (data) {
console.log(data.text);
});
```

[image]

Comment: `const url = "./prueba.pdf"`

Comment: But it does not read my pdf. This is the error that comes out: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './prueba.pdf'

Comment: Then use the correct path to the file.

Comment: I am using the file path just fine. Moreover, you can easily see in the image that the file is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path `./prueba.pdf` is *not* correct, unless you run the `node` command from the `..\api\src\routes` subdirectory, which I doubt.

Unlike paths in a `require` command, paths in an `fs.readFileSync` command are interpreted relative to the directory where you started the `node` process.

Comment: Thanks mate, that was the answer I was looking for.